# The closure of prime divisor is a prime divisor.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**[Statement]** (Hartshorne , Algebraic Geometry, II, section 6 , proposition 6.5 )

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one.
Also, let Z be a proper closed subset of $X$, and $U= X - Z$

Then, there is a surjective homomorphism $\text{Cl}\; X \to \text{Cl}\; U$ defined by $D= \sum n_i Y_i \mapsto \sum n_i(Y_i \cap U)$, where we ignore those $Y_i \cap U$ which are empty

---

[Question]

I have a question on the part of the proof on book which shows surjectivity.
He says,

> It is surjective because every prime divisor of $U$ is the restriction of its closure in $X.$

In this book, the definition of "prime divisor in $X$" is a closed **integral** subscheme of codimension one.

I wonder that the closure of prime divisor of $U$ in $X$ is still integral subscheme in $X$.

I know that integral $\Longleftrightarrow$ irreducible and reduced.

Since the closure of irreducible set is irreducible, it is sufficient to show that the closure of reduced scheme is reduced.

However, I'm stuck here. How can I prove this?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please do not use MathJax to format text. I've removed it for you.

Comment: By 'closure' wouldn't he mean 'scheme-theoretic closure'?

Comment: @KReiser , thank you!

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer , you're right, I understand now , Thank you so much!